# How to disable an app from being run on tablets?

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-screen-support

When I say tablets I mean devices with aspect ratios that are leaning towards the more square size, in other words not 16:9. I've used the code from [developers.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) to declare the app is for handsets only:

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

but now that I published my app I can't install it on my phone which is a handset with the dimensions 2560x1440 which is still 16:9. I get the "Your device isn't compatible with this version" message.

Now I'm asking myself if the code above is not necessarily to block tablets but to block all devices with high resolution which Android might define as "not handsets". I want the app to be available to handsets of any resolution but to be blocked to devices that don't resemble a handset aspect ratio. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you even want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> but now that I published my app I can't install it on my phone which is a handset with the dimensions 2560x1440 which is still 16:9. I get the "Your device isn't compatible with this version" message.

Your device's screen density is higher than `xhdpi`, and your `<compatible-screens>` element does not list higher density options than `xhdpi`.

> When I say tablets I mean devices with aspect ratios that are leaning towards the more square size, in other words not 16:9.

There are devices that can run Android apps that are phone-sized with more-square aspect ratios (e.g., BlackBerry Passport).

> I want the app to be available to handsets of any resolution but to be blocked to devices that don't resemble a handset aspect ratio. Is there a way to do this?

No.